# Why celery task is created but not received

Tags: django, task, celery

I am using celery with Django. The tasks are defined in tasks.py. The execution is done in views.py using `task.delay()`.

I have a total of 32 different tasks. All the tasks are created well (meaning all the task IDs are created). The problem is that the first task is not received unless I restart celery on my localhost. Occasionally, the second task is not received either.

Why does this happen, and how can I make this work correctly?

Comment: You mean after edit your celey task?

Comment: Hi seuling, I am not sure what you want to ask, but I don't edit my tasks , like I mentioned above the first task is received only after I restarted my celery on my localhost. If I execute the tasks second time without restarting celery, the first task will not be received by the workers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to solve the problem, but still don't understand completely why this happened. Basically, I killed all the running python process, and then all the tasks are received well.

If someone knows why, please help to understand, thanks a lot.